# Replace a sting in shell with special character #shellscripting

Tags: shell, unix

Please help me to replace a sting with new updated stinging in multiple files.

Input:

```
DNEXUS_USERNAME="$(NEXUS_USER_NAME)" -DNEXUS_PASSWORD="$(NEXUS_PASSWORD)"
```

New string:

```
DNEXUS_USERNAME_NEW='$(NEW_NEXUS_TKN_NAME)' -DNEXUS_PASSWORD_NEW='$(NEW_NEXUS_TKN)
```

Issue: when I'm trying to replace the sting by sed command it's being consider as a special character i.e. ($) . please suggest me the correct way to do this task

Comment: Is this bash or powershell?

Comment: it's bash script

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a need to reference the $ in the file at all:

```
sed -i 's/NEXUS_USER_NAME/NEW_NEXUS_TKN_NAME/g;s/NEXUS_PASSWORD/NEW_NEXUS_TKN/g' file
```

Comment: But In the next stage in the same file, there is one more sting which is having the same variable with different value.  So it wont work if i replace the variable. I will required to replace the full string only

Comment: Can you add that to the question?